# Interface<r> where r needs to be several different values. Google Play Api

Tags: java, android

While working on the Google Play API, I found this on the developers.google site:

> ...Do not use anonymous listeners. Anonymous listeners are implementations of a listener interface that are defined inline...

So the only other way I can think to implement an interface is to do it with the class... ie. Game implements GameHelperListener.

However, with the listeners that I normally would have written as Anonymous, there are several 'types' I need to implement:

```
implements
ResultCallback<TurnBasedMultiplayer.InitiateMatchResult>,
ResultCallback<TurnBasedMultiplayer.CancelMatchResult>,
ResultCallback<TurnBasedMultiplayer.UpdateMatchResult>,
ResultCallback<TurnBasedMultiplayer.LeaveMatchResult>,
ResultCallback<TurnBasedMultiplayer.LoadMatchesResult>,
ResultCallback<TurnBasedMultiplayer.LoadMatchResult> {
```

This throws an error statement:

> The interface ResultCallback cannot be implemented more than once with different arguments

How can I fix this to take multiple types of the same interface? I need all of these.

Comment: You will need to create separate classes.

Comment: Would it be possible to create a set of superclasses who extend down to this class? Would I be able to pass this class as a listener to the interface implemented by the top class?

Comment: No. You cannot inherit from the same generic interface with different type parameters. The degree of separation between class and superclass doesn't matter.